# Obtain the value from a custom category attribute outside category page

Tags: php, magento

On my Magento homepage I try to list the subcategories from a certain category with some values from custom category attributes in it. The list is working but I can't obtain the values from the custom category attributes.

The output is blank. What I am doing wrong? The relevant attributes are category_subtitle and category_slidertext.

```
<?php
    $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
    $productsChildren = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(3);
    foreach ($productsChildren as $productCat) {
?>
<li>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <h2><?php $_category_subtitle = $productCat->getData('category_subtitle'); if($_category_subtitle): ?><span><?php echo $_category_subtitle; ?></span><?php endif; ?></h2>
            <?php $_category_slidertext = $productCat->getData('category_slidertext'); if($_category_slidertext): ?><h3><?php echo $_category_slidertext; ?></h3><?php endif; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($productCat) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View our products') ?> &gt;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 $productsChildren = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(3,0,false,true,false);
 $productsChildren->addAttributeToSelect('category_subtitle')
                  ->addAttributeToSelect('category_slidertext');
```

That will work if `$productsChildren` is an instance of the category collection.